# how to override default node attributes in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I want to override node attributes such as public ip which i am sending to each specific node as part of testing onto different nodes, i am using "knife node" edit for it.

I am unable to override the default attributes when i try to change the default attribute i get the below error while saving the node after editing "Node not updated, skipping node save"

Trying to add the below in default property in node edit, even i tried the override but it failed.Could someone give me any way
   through which i can achieve it

```
  "default": {
    "deploy": {
      "external_ip": "10.38.9.2" 
    }
  },
```

I didnt find any proper answers for this, so i created this question here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Tommy,

Directly from https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence

> An automatic attribute contains data that is identified by Ohai at the
>   beginning of every chef-client run. An automatic attribute cannot be
>   modified and always has the highest attribute precedence.

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can set default attributes in the manner you described.  However, the attribute you are setting is over-ridden by an Ohai automatic attribute.  Automatic attributes take preference over all other attributes, and as @tiago pointed out, are read only.

Assuming you are trying to change the ip address using chef, you will need to use a recipe to do this, rather than just an attribute.  That recipe would likely use an attribute such as `node[:set_ip_address]` or `node[:new_ip_address]` to store the desired value.  There is likely an existing cookbook that can do this, but I would recommend you verify that it also re-loads the ohai data after it changes the ipaddress, otherwise `node[:external_ip]` will still have the old value.